# feature extraction form matrixes with different length

Tags: python, machine-learning, cluster-analysis, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I have a data set which every row has a corresponding matrix with different length.

I have tried some ways for dimensionality reduction like averaging all the rows of a matrix which also ends to having the same number of features for every instance.

but I didn't achieve a good result in this way

now I want to use singular values as the representation of each matrix, but again every instance will have a different number of singular values as the matrixes have different lengths.

is there any way to use a classifier on a data set with a different number of features for each row?

thank you in advance.

Comment: if you ant to reduce the dimensionality of your data you can use PCA (see kernel trick for high dimensionalit). Anyway,  there is a few probability to keep some (2) of your original dimensions and reduce a third one only (or get poor results)

Comment: From the little information you give, it sounds to me like you are not representing the data in a meaningful way. It would be easier if you showed an example. However, if you simply reduce dimensionality, you will reduce variance, something you probably don't want. But more important: do the rows in your data set represent individual samples? If not, this is probably where you should start. Otherwise, you will probably not get meaningful output from any classifier.

Comment: each row of the data set is a matrix corresponding to an individual sample.